# extjs 4.1 How to show numbered and bullet in xtemplate

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I have a xtemplate in **http://jsfiddle.net/qbytj/**

here is my numbered and bullet in xtemplate

```
data: {
    x: '<table><tbody>'
       +'<tr><td colspan="4">'
       +' <ol><li>&#8203;my 1</li><li>my 2<br></li></ol>'
       +'</td></tr> </tbody></table>',
    y: '<table><tbody>'
       +'<tr><td colspan="4">'
       +' <ul><li>my 1</li><li>my 2</li><li>&#8203;</li></ul>'
       +'</td></tr></tbody></table>'
}
```

But that don't show numbered and bullet 
[image]

I want to show numbered and bullet in my xtemplate. How to fix that thanks

Comment: You have to restore the CSS styles that Ext overrides, specifically for that panel (using a custom CSS class), and for each type of element. That's a bit fastidious.

Comment: @rixo how to do that? I'm stupid :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to wrap your markup in a custom CSS class.

You can do that directly in your XTemplate's markup:

```
Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
    '<div cls="my-ct-class">',
        // ... rest of your template
    '</div>',
);
```

Or you can use the `cls` option of the component using the template. For example, if it is a panel:

```
Ext.widget('panel', {

    cls: 'my-ct-class',

    tpl: // ...
});
```

Then you must restyle everything that Ext has "reseted" and that you need... Here is the minimal CSS rule set needed to fix ordered and unordered lists, to put in a CSS file of your own (clean method) or in a `<style>` tag in your index.html (OK for testing):

```
.my-ct-class ol li {
    list-style:decimal;}
.my-ct-class ul li {
    list-style:disc;}
.my-ct-class ul ul li {
    list-style:circle;}
.my-ct-class ul, .my-ct-class ol {
    padding-left: 2em;}
```

Comment: I try that in http://jsfiddle.net/qbytj/2/ but not working :(. where is wrong? :(

Comment: My bad, I thought it would work without needing to specify the li element. Apparently it doesn't. I have updated my answer, and [forked your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rixo/qbytj/3/) for illustration.